# How to set "text-relative" tags or classifiers in the Visual Studio source code editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am developing a Visual Studio extension and I need to place tags, classifiers, or adornments in the source code window. I have got some line/column information provided by some source code analysis. For a first step, I could place them successfully. The problem comes when the user goes on modifying the source code: my "markers" quickly go out-of-sync.

I have found the following startup documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-creating-a-margin-glyph?view=vs-2017 and other similar pages. My understanding is that the default approach is that the main placement routine (like "*IEnumerable> ITagger.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)*") will be called each time the code is modified or scrolled on the screen. This is fine when the source code analysis is simple and fast. You can refresh very often.

However, I cannot do that. My analysis is much more complex and longer. I cannot refresh all the time. I understand I need "markers" in the source code window to be "text-relative", meaning I want them to be anchored to some text (originally placed at this line/column) and move with it when the user continue modifying the source code around.

- Is there some way to specify that "markers" (glyphs, syntax coloring tags, graphical tags in the text and BTW all the others such as tooltips, lightbulb suggestions, outlined text, etc) can be set to be "text-relative" so that they are automatically updated as the user types? Are there some examples?
- Or do I have to update the "markers" placement myself when the user modifies the code? How can I get the modification information (original cursor location, number of characters/lines added/removed)? I cannot seem to find this with the given SnapshotSpan objects.

> Terminology: When I say "text-relative", I mean the markers are "anchored" to some line-column location to fit some text when created initially and they move together with the text when the user updates the code. Other IDEs provide that by default: you created "markers" once and they moved together with the text until you remove them and create others.

Comment: Hi Stephane, you can check if answer below helps and if there's any update for this issue please feel free to let us know :)

Comment: Hi Lance! Any idea on that? Is Visual Studio able to automatically move markers in the text as the user continues editing? Or is it able at least to provide me what has changed in the file to I can update markers location? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not that familiar with markers :{ So I involved DevPreSupport to help research it, hope you can get some help from his answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have tried the below link, it should match your requirement about "text-relative" tags

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-extension-with-an-editor-item-template?view=vs-2017

**Create a text-relative adornment extension**

> The Editor Text Adornment template creates a text-relative adornment
>   that decorates all instances of the text character 'a' by using a box
>   that has a red outline and a blue background. It is text-relative
>   because **the box always overlays the 'a' characters**, even when they are
>   moved or reformatted.

Add example codes:

```
public TextAdornment1(IWpfTextView view)
    {
        if (view == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("view");
        }

        this.layer = view.GetAdornmentLayer("TextAdornment1");

        this.view = view;
        this.view.LayoutChanged += this.OnLayoutChanged;

        // Create the pen and brush to color the box behind the a's
        this.brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff));
        this.brush.Freeze();

        var penBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        penBrush.Freeze();
        this.pen = new Pen(penBrush, 0.5);
        this.pen.Freeze();
    }

internal void OnLayoutChanged(object sender, TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ITextViewLine line in e.NewOrReformattedLines)
        {
            this.CreateVisuals(line);
        }
    }

 private void CreateVisuals(ITextViewLine line)
    {
        IWpfTextViewLineCollection textViewLines = this.view.TextViewLines;

        // Loop through each character, and place a box around any 'a'
        for (int charIndex = line.Start; charIndex < line.End; charIndex++)
        {
            if (this.view.TextSnapshot[charIndex] == 'a')
            {
                SnapshotSpan span = new SnapshotSpan(this.view.TextSnapshot, Span.FromBounds(charIndex, charIndex + 1));
                Geometry geometry = textViewLines.GetMarkerGeometry(span);
                if (geometry != null)
                {
                    var drawing = new GeometryDrawing(this.brush, this.pen, geometry);
                    drawing.Freeze();

                    var drawingImage = new DrawingImage(drawing);
                    drawingImage.Freeze();

                    var image = new Image
                    {
                        Source = drawingImage,
                    };

                    // Align the image with the top of the bounds of the text geometry
                    Canvas.SetLeft(image, geometry.Bounds.Left);
                    Canvas.SetTop(image, geometry.Bounds.Top);

                    this.layer.AddAdornment(AdornmentPositioningBehavior.TextRelative, span, null, image, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I was probably unclear (translation issue ;-)). In the adornment template (and the other related templates on glyph, tags, etc), the "marker" is text-relative in the sense that you compute the location relatively to the text. But you recompute *all* the locations of the *visible* markers each time the main function is called (CreateVisuals for Adornments, ITagger.GetTags for tags, etc), that each time a single character is modified in the code. (continued on next comment)

Comment: What I need is to compute the locations once in a while (my "defect" analysis is long and produce high-level "defects") and I need "markers" to move along with the text as the user types. Meaning, my analysis has placed a defect on a function name that goes wrong, let's say on line 45 and column 23 and we the user adds 3 lines and the cursor has moved 12 columns, I need the "marker" to automatically move to line 48 and column 35. (continued on next comment)

Comment: Does the API provide that (note that it exists on other IDEs)? Or does the API provide a way to get what has changed on edit (how many lines and columns the cursor has moved) so I can recompute locations (without the costly "defects" recomputation)?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. According to the definition of ITextView in link [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/enus/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2019, there is no such API for detecting user typing events. But the event arguments has an option called NewOrReformattedLines, this should reduce the compute cost during typing new words. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.textviewlayoutchangedeventargs.neworreformattedlines?view=visualstudiosdk-2019

Comment: For instance:`code` internal void OnLayoutChanged(object sender, TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ITextViewLine line in e.NewOrReformattedLines)
            {
                this.CreateVisuals(line);
            }
        }`code`

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply! Could you be more specific about your example, please? How to activate the OnLayoutChanged method? Which class should it be bound? Which class the CreateVisuals method comes from? Is it the method I am supposed to write?

Comment: Looking closer at the NewOrReformattedLines documentation, I cannot any information about "how much" the lines have changed. Indeed, if I have to recompute the "markers" location, then I need to know how many lines the NewOrReformattedLines have changed. I have probably missed something. Are there any examples on how to OnLayoutChanged and NewOrReformattedLines to get "what" has changed and "how much"? Thanks.

Comment: @Stephane, I edited the reply with sample codes,  let me know if it is helpful for you.